# JS - Why code does not run after async / await for promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have a sample code on TS playground represents my problem.
In an async function, I log the result after await for the promise, but only the code inside promise run, not the log outside of it. Could someone explain this problem?

Here is the code:

```
const asyncFnc = async () => {
    let result = false;
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // This log worked
            console.log('waited 5s');
            result = true;
        }, 5000);
    });
    // This log did not worked
    console.log(result);
}

asyncFnc();
```

And the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` sends the parent function to sleep until the promise on the right hand side settles (i.e. resolves or rejects).

Your promise **never** resolves or rejects. (i.e. you don't call `resolve`, make use of the second argument, or throw an exception).

Thus the parent function sleeps forever.

---

The idiomatic way to write this would be to avoid setting variables in the wider scope as a side effect, and just resolve with the values instead.

```js
const asyncFnc = async () => {
    const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('waited 5s');
            resolve(true);
        }, 5000);
    });
    console.log(result);
}

asyncFnc();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `resolve()` in your timeout